# Compute $1008^{189642}\pmod{2011}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to begin computation of $1008^{189642}\pmod{2011}$

I am quite lost trying to figure out how to go about this.

There are some "facts" I can find, but not sure how these can help me

- gcd(2011,1008) = 1.
- 2011 is prime.
- Prime factorisation of $1008$ is $2^4\times3^2\times7$

Comment: hint: fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem only yields the reduction $1008^{720}\mod 2011$.

Comment: $1008^{27}\equiv-13(\mod2011)$

Comment: @Mathematician42 $702$, not $720$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: You are right, that was a typo!

Comment: $$1008^{189642}\mod 2011\equiv 1476$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner says who ?

Comment: squaring,squaring,..

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Does exist an integer $n$ such that $\phi(n)=26$? Where $\phi$ is Euler totient function. How did you get that $1008^{27}\equiv-13(\mod2011)$?

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1008%5E189642+modulo+2011), @LeGrandDODOM.

Answer (score 3):

A pedestrian solution:

By Fermat's little theorem, $1008^{2010}\equiv 1 \bmod 2011$, and since $189642\equiv 702 \bmod 2010$, we get $1008^{189642}\equiv 1008^{702} \bmod 2011$.

A few iterations yield $1008^9\equiv 48 \bmod 2011$, hence $1008^{702} \equiv 48^{78} \bmod 2011 $.

Noting that $48^3 \equiv -13 \bmod 2011$, we get $48^{78}\equiv 13^{26}  \bmod 2011$.

Finally, $13^{26}  = 13^{15}\cdot 13^{11}\equiv 74 \cdot 183 \equiv 1476 \bmod 2011$.

Putting everything together, $1008^{189642}\equiv 1476 \bmod 2011$.

Comment: Shouldn't we calculate $189642 \mod 2010$ and not $\mod 2011$?, since we want $189642^{(2010k+t)}=189642^{2010k}*189642^t$

Comment: @RabMakh typo, sorry.

Comment: Plus one for "unsung hero."

Comment: Would you mind explaining how 1008^189642 ≡ 1008^702 mod 2011
and the steps you took to get   1008^9 ≡ 48 mod 2011, please? This is where I've previously had trouble trying to do this question by Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 3):

First at all $2011$ is prime. One has in the field $\mathbb F_{2011}$ as a first simplification
$$1008^{189642}=1008^{2011\cdot94+608}=1008^{94+608}=1008^{702}$$ since $2\cdot1008=2011+5$
$$1008^{702}=\left(\frac52\right)^{702}=\left(\frac52\right)^{2\cdot27\cdot13}=\left(\frac{25}{4}\right)^{27\cdot13}=\left(\frac{1548}{64}\right)^{9\cdot13}=\left(\frac{387}{16}\right)^{9\cdot13}$$ 
A solution of $16x=2011y+1$ is $(x,y)=(3645,29)$ so in $\mathbb F_{2011}$ one has $\dfrac{1}{16}=3645=1634$.

It follows $$\left(\frac{387}{16}\right)^{9\cdot13}=(387\cdot1634)^{117}=904^{117}$$ Calculations follow in $\mathbb F_{2011}$
$$904^5=551\\904^{30}=551^6=1188\\904^{90}=1188^3=1400\\904^{25}=754$$ Finally
$$904^{117}=1400\cdot754\cdot904^2=\color{red}{1476}$$

Answer (score 0):

Our starting point (see the other answers) is to calculate $1008^{702} \bmod 2011$.

Using the law of exponents and a base $2$ representation of $702$ (it translates into bracket placement), we need to calculate

$\quad x^{702} \equiv ((((((((x^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2\; \times $
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  ((((((x^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2 \; \times$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad ((((x^2)^2)^2)^2)^2\;  \times$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  (((x^2)^2)^2)^2 \; \times$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad ((x^2)^2)^2\; \times$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (x^2)^2 \; \times$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad x^2 \pmod {2011} \quad \text{where } x = 1008$

Setting constants and performing $\text{modulo } 2011$  calculations from the bottom up,

$\quad A = 1008^2 = 509$
$\quad B = 509^2 = 1673$
$\quad C = 1673^2 = 1628$
$\quad D = 1628^2 = 1897$
$\quad E = 1897^2 = 930$
$\quad F = 930^2 = 170\quad$ * intermediate
$\quad G = 170^2 = 746$
$\quad H = 746^2 = 1480\quad$ * intermediate
$\quad I = 1480^2 = 421$

ANS: $IGEDCBA \pmod {2011} \equiv 1476$